# How to label adjacent pages in data driven pages

Tags: arcgis-10.1, labeling, data-driven-pages, match-lines

I'm trying to create a mapbook using `ArcGIS 10.1` data driven pages. Its quite large and I want to create match lines or labels so that if you are looking at a page, there is text/labels showing you which page is adjacent to the top, bottom, left, right.

If I remember, correctly, this option was part of the data driven pages toolbar in 10.0, but it doesn't seem to be there now?

Comment: These help? http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s900000028000000 and http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s900000005000000 and http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/02/02/creating-dynamic-locator-maps-and-adding-page-effects-to-your-data-driven-pages/

Answer (score 2):

You have to prepare you data before hand with adjacency fields
using the [calculate adjacency fields tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//007000000009000000)

> > This tool creates eight new fields whose names are a combination of the in_field name and direction. Direction is abbreviated. For
> >     example, if the in_field name is "PageName" the new field names
> >     created by the tool would include: "PageName_N", "PageName_NE",
> >     "PageName_E", "PageName_SE", "PageName_S", "PageName_SW", "PageName_W"
> >     and "PageName_NW". If the in_field name is "MyPoly" the new field
> >     names would include: "MyPoly_N", "MyPoly_NE", "MyPoly_E", "MyPoly_SE",
> >     "MyPoly_S", "MyPoly_SW", "MyPoly_W" and "MyPoly_NW".
>
> You cannot specify names for the new fields. The tool uses default
>   names, though you can change field names after the tool has been run.
>
> You can use fields from a joined table.

I think this is actually what you want.
[neighbor label](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s900000039000000#ESRI_SECTION1_11E662D8C30946E9AC11C449F7C721A5)
There are many other label objects you can use.
[dynamic labels](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Adding_dynamic_text_for_your_map_book/00s900000029000000/)
I prefer to use [the locator map](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Creating_a_locator_map_for_a_map_book/00s900000028000000/). you can set it to highlight and label the current page differently than the neighbor pages.