# Matchlines with Data Driven Pages in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-driven-pages, strip-map, match-lines

I have a map book created via the Data Driven Pages tool in ArcGIS.  Specifically, I used the Strip Map option when I created the book. And I have employed the 'Angle' attribute of the index layer in order to rotate each page so that the route is (generally) shown west-to-east, with the north arrow turning dynamically with each page.

Now, I understand the labeling options for the Data Driven pages.  But I don't want to merely label the pages - I want to create vertical matchlines that appear on each page.  Can this be done, even as each record of the index is turned 'upright'?

Graphic matchline example:

[image]

*Credit/source: https://courses.cit.cornell.edu/arch465/arch367f07-workdwgs/notes/04.html*

Comment: Are you able to elaborate on or provide an illustration showing what you mean by "vertical match lines"? I've produced strip maps long before DDP but can't picture what you mean.

Comment: I would like to have match lines on each page (and in the same place on each page - say 1" from the left and right borders). My index layer is 15 pages and I'm using the 'Angle' attribute of the layer to keep each page horizontal (the dynamic north arrow rotates). I thought about inserting polylines in each rectangle of the index but then they would rotate as the pages advanced. I could send you a PDF that was sent to me that appears to do what I need... I just don't know how to create match lines as they did.

Comment: I received Jim's images and can see that this is a sophisticated requirement.  Matchlines seem to be designed to enable someone to line up their map book pages and I think this is only simple to do if all strip maps are drawn at the same scale and at the same approximate angle.  There is some [**background**](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/29083-Map-book-data-driven-pages-for-a-polyline-Grid-Index-vs-Strip-Map) to this request worth reviewing that shows Jim has put considerable research into his requirement before posting here.

Comment: I still don't understand what is needed. Is it something like "extent rectangle"? Could you please add an illustration (if Jim agrees).

Comment: radouxju, my original issue was somewhat tricky (and I don't believe that I have any of the sample graphics).  In summary,  I have a DD map series whose index was created with the default ArcGIS tools.  The indices follow a line, keeping it generally horizontal - thus each index has an 'Angle' attribute, used to 'turn' each page horizontal.

Match lines were used on each page. The trick was that on each page, the match lines were all shown at 90 degrees and about 1 inch from the left and right margins - on every page. The index angle attribute should prevent that from happening.

Comment: Additionally, as PolyGeo mentions above, I had already posted a query on the Esri forums. Within those posts I had uploaded three images showing what I meant. You can view that [**thread**](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/27077) by following the link.

Comment: @polygeo I *strongly* disagree with the removal of the cartography tag from this question. Matchlines are a cartographic design element, and while the specific task the asker is performing involves a strip map, match lines are not exclusive to them (and nor is my answer, which actually addresses both strip maps and standard grid maps).

Comment: @ChrisW I guess that I am quite conservative in my thinking about when the [tag:cartography] tag should be applied.  I would rather see the specific type(s) of map that is/are being asked about tagged rather than something that is generic.

Comment: @PolyGeo Yes, I've gotten that impression from the meta discussions with regard to the tag, and while I do agree that it might be a bit overused, this *particular* question covers a principle that falls under that heading (re my own comments in said meta discussion). On the other hand, strip-map adds nothing (actually narrows the focus) - it's just the type of map the OP was working on at the time. In some cases I think generic is better than focusing on the details which may not be essential to the topic (for example, the gis-principle tag).

Comment: @ChrisW In the asker's words "I used the Strip Map option when I created the book" so they are asking about Strip Maps.  It is fine to use answers to suggest alternatives to the functionality that someone is using (it's why I upvoted your answer) but that is what they are using and asking about.  They are also using and asking about matchlines and so the question is also tagged [tag:match-lines].  This is useful functionality that I am hoping is being considered for addition to Map Series for Strip Maps in ArcGIS Pro.

Answer (score 3):

Matchlines are typically a feature found on plans, not maps. I'm not aware of any tool to directly implement them in ArcGIS. It's possible there are such tools in some of the mapbook extensions available out there. However there is a workaround that can *roughly* do it.

First, you need to create a new feature class and actually draw in the matchlines where you want them. Sometimes matchlines are shown in different places on their matching pages rather than right at the 'official split' - that won't be possible here. You'll need to create single lines. You'll then symbolize that layer in your map in some obvious way (overly thick and dashed for example).

Once you have the lines, you'll need to potentially modify your reference feature grid. If it doesn't already have them, you need adjacent neighbor fields. There's a tool for this that would work in some cases ([Calculate Adjacent Fields](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//007000000009000000)), otherwise you just manually add an attribute and populate it yourself (which can also help control what your match line text says).

With that, you can insert a [Dynamic Text element](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s900000013000000) into the layout near the edges of the page. Your map view will rotate as you go from page to page, and it's possible the exact location of the matchlines may move as well and their rotation definitely will. However these text elements won't, so you need to locate them somewhere that will *generally* be near where the matchlines will appear.

It's not pretty or ideal, and is basically just taking adjacent page labels out of the map collar and moving them over the map itself. Related: [How to label adjacent pages in data driven pages](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/56642/)

Comment: This is what I do, draw them manually in a separate layer.